# "Improve Location Accuracy" question won't stop coming up

Tags: notifications

Immediately, no matter if I hit "yes" or "no", it will pop up one second later when I'm on Tinder. No matter how many times I answer, it will just come right back up immediately. I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling the app, and figuring with my wifi settings. Solutions?

Answer (score 0):

I use an app callled "automagic premium"

I created a flow that launches whenever "network" appear in `"System.secure.location_providers_allowed"`

It pops up a message box causing the prompt we both hate to go away - and never be agreed to.